# How to select a specific group of elements from a database?

Tags: sql

I'm working on a database which can be synthetized like:

```
TAB1: NICK, COUNTRY
TAB2: PLAYER, FRIEND
```

In TAB2, PLAYER and FRIEND both can connect to respective a TAB1.NICK; NICK is a primary key, PLAYER and FRIEND are both foreign keys.

I need to find how many players are friends only with people from the same country, but, after a couple of afternoons I still can't manage to do it...

The last thing I tried:

```
select count(*) from TAB1 as p1
join TAB2 as f1 on p1.nick = f1.player
join TAB1 as p2 on f1.friend = p2.nick
where p1.country is not null and p2.country is not null
and p1.country = p2.country
and not exists (select * from TAB1 as p0
    join TAB2 as f0 on p0.nick = f0.nick
    join TAB1 as p3 on f0.friend = p3.nickname
    where p0.country is not null and p3.country is not null
    and p0.country <> p3.country)
```

Comment: Database schema please? (Relationships esp.)

Comment: Edited, sorry for the missing stuff.

Comment: You should design the tables so that none of the columns stores nulls, so you don't have to futz around with 'is not null' conditions.  It makes little sense to say "player p1 has a friend but I don't know who it is", which is what a null in tab2.friend would mean; likewise for tab2.player.  And while there might be a business case for identifying a nick even though you don't know their country, it is simpler to say "there shall always be a country code supplied for every valid nick" (or "a nick will not be valid unless we know the country the person hails from - or claims to hail from").

Comment: @Jonathan: We accepted NULLs as COUNTRY because the main data of the database is some not showed here. We didn't want to waste precious data when the script we used couldn't retrieve only the country, so we kept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the query up piece-meal - start with the easier parts, and continue to the harder.  The key observation to making it work is that you need to use two joins to the same table.  This query gives the list of pairs where the two people come from the same country:

```
SELECT p1.nick, p1.country, p2.nick, p2.country
  FROM tab2
  JOIN tab1 AS p1 ON tab2.player = p1.nick
  JOIN tab1 AS p2 ON tab2.friend = p2.nick
 WHERE p1.country = p2.country
```

This counts the number of players with one or more friends from the same country:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p1.nick)
  FROM tab2
  JOIN tab1 AS p1 ON tab2.player = p1.nick
  JOIN tab1 AS p2 ON tab2.friend = p2.nick
 WHERE p1.country = p2.country
```

And, if what you are after is people who only have friends from the same country as they come from (as suggested in the comment), then you need to establish that the player has no friends where the friend's country is not the player's country.  You get into the interesting question: does some who has no friends get counted?  Since they don't have any friends from the same country, they're not counted by the query below:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p1.nick)
  FROM tab2
  JOIN tab1 AS p1 ON tab2.player = p1.nick
  JOIN tab1 AS p2 ON tab2.friend = p2.nick
 WHERE p1.country = p2.country
   AND NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT *
              FROM tab2 AS t2
              JOIN tab1 AS p3 ON t2.player = p3.nick
              JOIN tab1 AS p4 ON t2.friend = p4.nick
             WHERE p3.country != p4.country
               AND p3.nick = p1.nick
           )
```

This says "players who have at least one friend from their own country and where there is no friend for the player who comes from a different country".

Comment: Won't this only show people who have friends from the same country, not those who **only** have friends from the same country?  I'm thinking he needs a `NOT EXISTS` as well.

Comment: JNK is right, this query counts just the friends from the same country and doesn't consider the ones from a different place.

Comment: @JNK, @Gurzon: edits made ... as usual, it is easy to build a complex query if you do it in stages.  Thanks for pointing me in the right (or more nearly right) direction.

Comment: @Johnathan - +1 for the Edit.  FYI from the original post: **I need to find how many players are friends only with people from the same country**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TAB2.PLAYER, TAB1.COUNTRY
  FROM TAB2 PLAYER_TAB2
  JOIN TAB1 PLAYER_TAB1 ON TAB1.NICK = TAB2.PLAYER
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM TAB2
                     JOIN TAB1 ON TAB1.NICK = TAB2.FRIEND
                              AND TAB1.COUNTRY != PLAYER_TAB1.COUNTRY
                    WHERE TAB2.PLAYER = PLAYER_TAB2.PLAYER)
```